# Query to output results using "like"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I might be over-analyzing this but I have 13,000 records stored in a temp table that only has one column.

I'm trying to determine if those records exist in another database/table but there's no key between the two other than the one column.

The query I run has to use LIKE so something like this...

```
declare @string Varchar(25) = (select top 1 * from accts)
select content from db2..[mc3] where content like '%'@string+'%'
```

But I have check to see which one's are in there but I don't want to do it manually one at a time.

Is there a way to have it programmatically go through all of my accounts to see which one's are in that database/table?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may take a while, but you can get the matching ones using:

```
select a.??
from accts a 
where exists (select 1
              from db2..mc3 
              where mc3.content like '%' + a.?? +'%'
             );
```

This gets accounts that are in `mc3` according to your rule.

I should note:  performance will be pretty bad.  Better than a cursor but that's not saying much.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  I'm running it now and yeah, the performance is pretty bad but working nonetheless.  Any recommendation on how to speed up the process?  Thanks again.

Comment: @mikevoorisdankellyadventures . . . In SQL Server, I don't really know.  The only way to speed this type of query is to use n-gram indexes.  You can implement them manually in SQL Server (a bit of work).  Postgres supports them directly.